# .net mvc limit results with show more link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I would like to only display 2 results on my partial view with a show more link displayed if there are more results. My query which will display all results is:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetContacts(int id)
{
    var contacts = from c in db.CustomerContact
                   where c.CustomerID == id
                   orderby c.Surname
                   select c;

    return PartialView("_GetContacts", contacts);
}
```

Do I need to have two queries, one to count the number of results?

Would like to use jquery to show more results by expanding div.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: This tutorial on progressive enhancement may point you in that direction http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/twitter-style-paging-with-aspnet-mvc-and-jquery

Comment: Looks promising. will test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the quantity of elements that your query usually returns it would be a good idea to use a query to retrieve just two elements and use a different query to show the rest of elements when your users ask for it.

To avoid loading all your results always you can use an AJAX call to server on the link to show more.

However, if your query usually returns few elements you can use just one query to load all of them and show two or more through show more link click.

Comment: There shouldn't be more than six results for this particular query so one query will do it then.

Comment: Sure, if you aren't expecting much info then a single query will do the trick (unless each element on the returned data is really huge).

Comment: Solved this with some help from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3379112/1472203 and by returning a different partial view based on the result which is called with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var contacts = ....
return contacts.OrderBy(c => c.curname)
    .Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize);
```

You have to parameters here `pagesize` and `currentPage` for the first two items, pass `pageSize = 2` and `currentPage = 1` for more items(2 items per time) pass current page = 2 and so on.